# How to support iTunes on Luna?

Tags: software-installation, codec, music, macbook

I have installed Luna alongside on my macBook. Now i want to play my iTunes music, but it seems that Luna can't support it.

Is there any codec package to support apple iTunes music files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that your music files must not be DRM protected then you need `libavcodec-extra-53` codec.

You can easily install it via terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53
```